# Display Post co-authored in Author Page

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am using co-author plus and I have posts in my site that are done by multiple authors. I would like that when I click on the co-author's author page, I will be able to get the posts that he/she co-authored.

For now, I am using a vanilla WP_Query call to primary authors. I followed db trail and the co-authors are posted on the wp_term_taxonomy table, but I am unsure on how to query and get that data.

Here is my paramters:

```
$arg = array(
        'author'        => strval($user_id),
        'post_per_page' => 10,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'paged'         => strval($page)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Co-Authors Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) to assign the authors and the post will show **automatically** on both author pages. I've used it and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template functions given by Co-Authors Plus plugin such as,

1. coauthors_posts_links() - Co-Authors Plus equivalent of the_author_posts_link() template tag.
2. coauthors() - Co-Authors Plus equivalent of the_author() template tag.

Please refer to their [documentation](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/)